# How can i limit the data from Yii2 DataProvider?

Tags: php, mysql, yii2

I want to limit the data I get from Yii2 ActiveDataProvider to 10 and here is the code of my controller:

```
use app\forms\MerchantSearchForm;
use Yii;
use yii\data\ActiveDataProvider;

  $newMembersDataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
        'query' => $this->merchantManager->getQuery()->limit(10)
        ]);
```

But instead of the first 10 results i get all the rows which are more than 2000.
I know i could use the code above so i can limit theresults to 10 per page:

```
$newMembersDataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
            'query' => $this->merchantManager->getQuery(),
            'pagination' => ['pageSize' => 10]
            ]);
```

But i don't want pagination in my case. I just want the first 5 results from the table.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

OK! i think i found it. Limit will work only if i set first the pagination to false. If anyone else have the same problem, this is the easy way to go. So here is the working code:

```
$newMembersDataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
            'query' => $this->merchantManager->getQuery()->limit(10),
            'pagination' => false
            ]);
```